# how do I post json to web api .net core?

Tags: .net

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var requestData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "FirstName", user.FirstName},
    { "LastName", user.LastName },
    { "Date_Of_Birth", user.Date_Of_Birth.ToString()},
    { "Gender", user.Gender},
    { "Status", user.Status.ToString()}
};
request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7169/api/User/Add"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData)
};
var response = client.PostAsync(request.RequestUri,request.Content);
```

My current code is not working ?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is not working? Also, you should be awaiting the `PostAsync()` call.

Comment: I have a razor page, on post i am trying to call external web api,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simplify this code to this:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var request = new AddUserRequest
 {
    FirstName = "Test",
    LastName = "Test",
    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
    //...
 };
 var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:7169/api/User/Add", request);
```

Comment: it was my api [FromForm]

Comment: You run async method client.PostAsync(request.RequestUri,request.Content); without await. Maybe that is the reason why it is not working.

Comment: any wasy I did both

Comment: When you debug the code what result do you get? statusCode, reasonPhrase or any exception?

Comment: I sloved it it was unsupported type

Comment: So maybe there is a problem with Content-Type accepted by your web api.